# navigate through records in Telerik popup control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, window

Hi i have a popup control, which displays the info of a row which i have clicked, i want to also have a next and previous button which will go to the next or previous record depending on what button is clicked, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [this code](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdcollectingdatainnewwindow.html) for starter - I suppose it can be adopted to use RadWindow instead of browser popup - and the buttons inside the popup collect the date from next/previous row and pass it to the popup, you should be set.